# How to use Qt MediaDevices type to switch AudioOutput device

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I think I'm missing something here, but I can't figure out how to set a AudioOutput device from MediaDevices audioOutputs list with the QML Components

```
audioOutput: AudioOutput {
    id: playerOutput
    device: mediaDevices.defaultAudioOutput
    onDeviceChanged: {
        console.log("Output device changed " + device)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(mediaDevices.audioOutputs)
    }
}

MediaDevices {
    id: mediaDevices
}
```

The 2 devices are showing:

```
QAudioDevice(2, Built in earpiece (IN2023), false, Output),
QAudioDevice(3, Built in speaker (IN2023), false, Output)
```

but I don't understand how to change it, I've tried `playerOutput.setDevice()` description and id but it wants a `QAudioDevice` (it only provides description, id and mode, the documentation for both is very vague:

> This property can be used to select an output device from the
> QtMultimedia::MediaDevices::audioOutputs() list.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-mediadevices.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-audiooutput.html#device-prop

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an object from `mediaDevices.audioOutputs` to the `devices` property of your `AudioOutput`.

```
playerOutput.device = mediaDevices.audioOutputs[index]
```

where `index` is a valid index in the `audioOutputs` list.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtMultimedia

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello AudioOutput")

    MediaDevices {
        id: mediaDevices
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaPlayer
        source: "qrc:/Test_ogg_mp3_48kbps.wav"
        audioOutput: AudioOutput {
            id: playerOutput
            device: mediaDevices.defaultAudioOutput
            onDeviceChanged: { console.log("Output device changed " + device) }
            Component.onCompleted: { console.log(mediaDevices.audioOutputs) }
        }
    }

    component MediaPlayerButton : Rectangle {
        id: button
        property alias text: label.text
        property bool active: false
        signal clicked

        width: 100; height: 40; radius: 10
        color: button.active ? "tomato" : "ghostwhite"
        border.color: "gainsboro"
        border.width: buttonMouseArea.containsMouse ? 4 : 2

        Text {
            id: label
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pointSize: 18
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: buttonMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onClicked:  button.clicked()
        }
    }

    Column {
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Row {
            spacing: 10

            MediaPlayerButton {
                text: qsTr("Play")
                active: mediaPlayer.playbackState === MediaPlayer.PlayingState
                onClicked: { mediaPlayer.play() }
            }

            MediaPlayerButton {
                text: qsTr("Pause")
                active: mediaPlayer.playbackState === MediaPlayer.PausedState
                onClicked: { mediaPlayer.pause() }
            }

            MediaPlayerButton {
                text: qsTr("Stop")
                active: mediaPlayer.playbackState === MediaPlayer.StoppedState
                onClicked: { mediaPlayer.stop() }
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: mediaDevices.audioOutputs

            Row {
                spacing: 10

                Rectangle {
                    id: r
                    width: 40; height: 40; radius: 20
                    color: mediaPlayer.audioOutput.device === mediaDevices.audioOutputs[index] ? "tomato" : "ghostwhite"
                    border.color: "gainsboro"
                    border.width: jackMouseArea.containsMouse ? 4 : 1

                    MouseArea {
                        id: jackMouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        hoverEnabled: true
                        onClicked: playerOutput.device = mediaDevices.audioOutputs[index]
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: r.verticalCenter
                    font.pointSize: 12
                    text: mediaDevices.audioOutputs[index].description
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why didn't I think of that ahaha thank you so much!